# How does a half-open scan work in Nmap?

Tags: nmap

Here in Nmap we have `-sS` option, which starts a "half-open scan."

```
    ➜  ~ sudo nmap -sS 192.168.1.4
    Password:
    Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-07-04 20:23 CST
    Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.4
    Host is up (0.000082s latency).
    Not shown: 999 closed ports
    PORT      STATE SERVICE
    49159/tcp open  unknown
```

then I use `-sT` option, which start a "full connection"

```
    ➜  ~ sudo nmap -sT 192.168.1.4
    Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-07-04 20:23 CST
    Nmap scan report for 192.168.1.4
    Host is up (0.00018s latency).
    Not shown: 999 closed ports
    PORT      STATE SERVICE
    49159/tcp open  unknown
```

The results of these two scans are exactly the same.

Question: How does a "half-open" TCP scan work, and can I simply use it instead of "full connection scan"?

Comment: Relevant documentation: https://nmap.org/book/man-port-scanning-techniques.html

Answer (score 1):

The -sT option does a full 3 way handshake. The -sS option is a SYN only scan. It never makes the full connection. A syn scan waits for a SYN/ACK (SA) or a RESET packet. If it gets either it knows how to mark the connection. The -sT option performs a full connection waiting for the S/SA/A flags.